# Passing a value from a CustomAdapter to Another Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible to call a function from another class inside a function?

**EDIT**

I have an `Integer` variable `num_items` in my `MainActivity.class` that will store the number of items in the `ListView` of my `Cart.class`. My `Cart` has a `CustomAdapter` which consists of an `ImageView`, `TextViews`, and a `Delete Button`.

How can I call  `public void cart_items(int x)` of `MainActivity.class` in the `Delete_button.OnClick` to pass a certain value.?

Here is a code from my `CustomAdapter.class`

```
holder.del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                remove(getItem(position));
                y = Double.parseDouble(data.getPrice()) * Double.parseDouble(data.getQty());
                ((Cart)getContext()).change_total(y);

               //How Can I pass data.getQty() to the MainActivity method?
            }
    });
```

I have this in my `MainActivity.class`

```
public void cart_items(int num) {
    cartnum = num +cartnum;

    if(cartnum == 0 || cartnum == 1 ) {
        cart_items_tv.setText("(" +String.valueOf(cartnum) + " item)");
    } else
        cart_items_tv.setText("(" +String.valueOf(cartnum) + " items)");
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible like in any other language.

Comment: Possible? yes. Good idea? Not really.

Comment: I tried that format but it didn't worked. got an error says `cannot resolve getContext()`.

Comment: Why not a good idea? Inside fragment it's a very good idea to communicate with parent Activity

Comment: @Selvin so can you please show me to do it?

Comment: Obviously not all classes has such method... What didn't you understand with this compile time error? Obviously you can do this only with classes which are derived from classes which have such method

Comment: The problem is not the call of the other method .. what are you trying to do ? what you want from using context ?? please show us the code relevant to this if you can

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you don't need to access the activity to call it. You need to create an object of the class. Also, you're probably looking for int x, not Integer x.

```
class MainClass {
    public void function(int x) {
        AnotherClass newClass = new AnotherClass();
        newClass.function2(239);
    }
}

class AnotherClass {
    public void function2(int x) {
        //Do something more
    }
}
```

Comment: well Integer is a int wrapped in a class, so it will passed by reference and not by value like a primitive. That means in theory after the function call returns and Integer x was the parameter and the value of x changed, the caller function can retrieve the new value.

Comment: @Alex No. The Integer class is immutable. So you can't change the int inside of it. So there is no difference in terms of practicality in this case .

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyHelper {

public static String myFun() {
    String unique = "any text";

    return unique;

}
}
```

from any where in your application call myFun function like this:
MyHelper.myFun();